# Two Magento stores put one of them under maintenace

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a Magento installation with two domains, domain1.com and domain2.com, domain1.com is the primary domain and I would like to put it under maintenance without affecting domain2.com

Comment: How are both stores setup? Are you using subdirectories, subdomains, seperate domains, etc. ?

Comment: Separate domains

Answer (score 0):

If the websites are separated by folders either subdomains or subdirectories, you can add the maintenance.flag file (no body required) to that directory, effectively putting it in maintenance mode.